# Keep getting this message: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: quantifier does not follow a repeatable item at offset 2

Tags: php, regex

Keep getting this message:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: quantifier does not follow a repeatable item at offset 2 in ...
```

Here's the applicable excerpt from the config file:

```
// config file excerpt:
'swap_image_refs' => [
    'callback' => new \SimpleHtml\Transform\ReplaceRegex(),
    'params' => ['regex' => '!/(+*?)/images/!', 'replace' => '/images/$1/'],
],
```

Here's the `__invoke()` method from the class called:

```
public function __invoke(string $html, array $params = []) : string
{
    $regex = $params['regex'] ?? '';
    $replace = $params['replace'] ?? '';
    $text = (!empty($regex))
          ? preg_replace($regex, $replace, $html)
          : $html;
    return $text ?? $html;
}
```

The code works ... but the replacement wasn't made.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling out the pertinent bits, you get this:

```
$regex = '!/(+*?)/images/!';
$replace = '/images/$1/';
$contents = file_get_contents('https://unlikelysource.com/about');
$text = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $contents);
```

The problem is in the regex (is always is, isn't it?).  The regex, as stated *doesn't match anything*!  Here's the corrected regex:

```
$regex = '!/(.+?)/images/!';
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The separation of qualifiers and quantifiers is a basic concept of regular expressions. You define what to match and how often.

`+*?` are all quantifiers, they specify how often something should match. So you're missing what to match.

Try `(/(.+)/images/)`

- The `.` is an qualifier that represents any character (except `\n`, depending on modifier `s`).
- `+` means at least once
- `()` can be used as delimiters without loosing the special meaning - just treat it as group 0
- `*` is the quantifier meaning "any amount" - it doesn't do anything in this case.
- `?` can have two meanings. If it follows a `+` or `*` it will trigger ungreedy (shortest) matches. Following a qualifier it means none or one.